# How to Manage Public Key with Asymmetric Cryptography

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, key-management, ios, asymmetric, objective-c

I'm working on an iOS chat project using **Firebase RealTime Database.**

I want to use **asymmetric cryptography** for the management of messages between two users ..

Browsing the net I found an excellent library **[Themis](https://github.com/vixentael/zka-example)** and for security reasons, in the documentation, advised not to save the **public keys** in the database but instead recommended to save **public keys** using a mediation service such as **keybase.io**.

This is very difficult for me to understand ... has anyone had experience with **keybase.io** or with other services?

can you suggest me some understandable ways to save the **public keys** with **PKI** avoiding the database?

Answer (score 2):

The recommendation is based on the fact that it's harder to stealthy compromise a public mediation service than a single service. If they compromise keybase, with a lot of users, someone will very soon detect something wrong and warn the administrators.

On the other hand, if someone hacks your service and changes public keys, it can take a while until someone sees it. It's easier to compromise data when there are few clients, and your service will surely have way less clients than keybase.

Comment: So what can you suggest to process a chat in total tranquility? if there are examples you can make me understand what are the right steps to do? or which services are used? if I can use Firebase Real Time Database to structure your database in security? honestly I never used mediators (if they really are useful ..) keybase currently seems a simple chat and it is not easy to understand ... any suggestion with or without mediators is really accepted .. for me it is important to create a service in total security